# Como escolher todos os arquivos com a mesma extensão em várias subpastas no TFS 2018?

Tags: team-foundation-server

Nas release definitions do TFS 2018 mais especificamente na task de archive, eu tenho várias subpastas, que podem ou não ter mais subpastas dentro delas, e eu quero que a task execute apenas encima dos arquivos com uma mesma extensão dentro do último nível de pasta.

Para visualizar melhor, meu diretório está mais ou menos assim: 
arquivos:
  index:
    itens:
      prontuario.txt
    teste:
      lista.txt
  direcionamento:
    nomes:
      clientes:
        antigos:
          homens:
            relacao.txt

Meu objetivo nesse caso é usar a task de archive para "zipar" todos os arquivos com uma mesma extensão, no exemplo: ".txt".

Tentei com as "wildcards" e fiz mais ou menos assim: 
arquivos/**/*.txt

Não obtive o resultado desejado, que seriam os arquivos de texto do exemplo.

Comment: Você quer pegar os arquivos na última pasta e compactar ou fazer isso na estrutura que você colocou só com os arquivos de extensão .txt?

Comment: Gostaria de fazer isso em toda a estrutura.

Comment: Estou encerrando essa pergunta por ter feito de uma outra maneira, eu copiei todos os arquivos para uma terceira pasta e só depois compactei os arquivos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu copiei todos os arquivos para uma terceira pasta e só depois compactei os arquivos.

Para isso usei a task de "copy" para levar os arquivos selecionados para uma outra pasta e de lá usei a task "archive" para finalmente compactar os arquivos.